# How to create elements of a struct with a Mutex field

Tags: rest, http, go, timeout, mutex

I have a `Get()` function:

```
func Get(url string) *Response {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return &Response{}
    }
    // res.Body != nil when err == nil
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ReadAll: %v", err)
    }
    reflect.TypeOf(body)
    return &Response{sync.Mutex(),string(body), res.StatusCode}
}
```

as well as a `Read()` function:

```
func Read(url string, timeout time.Duration) (res *Response) { 
    done := make(chan bool) 

    go func() {
        res = Get(url)      
        done <- true        
    }()     
        select {    // As soon as either
    case <-done:    // done is sent on the channel or 
    case <-time.After(timeout): // timeout
        res = &Response{"Gateway timeout\n", 504}

    }
    return
}
```

the `Response` type returned by the functions is defined as:

```
type Response struct {
    Body       string
    StatusCode int
}
```

This read function makes use of the `Get()` function and also implements a timeout. The problem is that a data race can occur if the timeout occurs and the `Get()` response is written to `res` at the same time in `Read()`.

I have a plan for how to solve this. It is to use Mutex. To do this, I would add a field to the `Response` struct:

```
type Response struct {
    mu         sync.Mutex
    Body       string
    StatusCode int
}
```

so that the `Response` can be locked. However, I'm not sure how to fix this in the other parts of the code.

My attempt looks like this, for the Get():

```
func Get(url string) *Response {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return &Response{}
    }
    // res.Body != nil when err == nil
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ReadAll: %v", err)
    }
    reflect.TypeOf(body)
    return &Response{sync.Mutex(),string(body), res.StatusCode} // This line is changed.
}
```

and for the `Read()`:

```
func Read(url string, timeout time.Duration) (res *Response) { 
    done := make(chan bool) 
    res = &Response{sync.Mutex()} // this line has been added

    go func() { 
        res = Get(url)      
        done <- true        
    }()     
        select {    
    case <-done:    
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        res.mu.Lock()
        res = &Response{sync.Mutex(), "Gateway timeout\n", 504} // And mutex was added here.

    }
    defer res.mu.Unlock()
    return
}
```

This "solution" generates these errors:

```
./client.go:54: missing argument to conversion to sync.Mutex: sync.Mutex()
./client.go:63: missing argument to conversion to sync.Mutex: sync.Mutex()
./client.go:63: too few values in struct initializer
./client.go:73: missing argument to conversion to sync.Mutex: sync.Mutex()
./client.go:95: cannot use "Service unavailable\n" (type string) as type sync.Mutex in field value
./client.go:95: cannot use 503 (type int) as type string in field value
./client.go:95: too few values in struct initializer
```

What is the correct way of using Mutex in this case?

Comment: Try replacing sync.Mutex() with sync.Mutex{}

Comment: That solved some things... thx

Comment: This seems all wrong and even more racy than the old code. Don't put the mutex inside your struct, keep it in Read and synchronize access to `res`. Maybe even better: get rid of the named return parameter and return either the value from Get or your error sentinel. Maybe even better: Transfer the response from Get to read via a channel.

Comment: Thx Volker. How is it wrong? As far as I can see there can be no data race now.

Comment: Access to the named return `res` is unsynchronised, thus racy.

Comment: How can it be? I locked it in `select{}`. And the go-routine is started AFTER I have initialized the res.

Comment: Writing to res in the go routine is unsynchronized.

Comment: Even after getting this sorted out, this is the wrong way to timeout an http request. Set the http `Client.Timeout`. You're not providing any way to cancel an in-flight request, which may never release its resources.

Answer (score 2):

While your answer with Volker's guidance is good, you might want to consider using a non default `http.Client` so that you can set a `Timeout` on the client making the request (then you don't have to worry about handling the timeouts yourself).

Answer (score 1):

I followed Volker's suggestion and used a channel to solve the problem.

```
func Read(url string, timeout time.Duration) (res *Response) { 
    done := make(chan bool) // A channel
    resChan := make(chan *Response)

    go func() { 
        resChan <- Get(url) 
        done <- true    
    }()     
    select {    
        case <-done:
            res = &Response{}    
        case <-time.After(timeout):
            res = &Response{"Gateway timeout\n", 504} 
    }
    return
}
```

Now, there can be no simultaneous writes to res. It's going to be either the timeout or the returned value of `Get(url)`.